# Can I use "time on page" to trigger an adwords conversion?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I want to know if anyone has successfully used a "time on page" approach towards triggering google adwords conversion events?  ie. Triggering a conversion event after someone has been on my website for 60 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done it myself, but if you're just referring to the standard [Adwords Conversion Tracking](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115794) snippet, it probably wouldn't be too difficult to do using something like this:

```
<script>
var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
var google_conversion_language = "en_US";
var google_conversion_format = "1";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "Purchase";
var google_conversion_value = 1
setTimeout(function(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
},60000) //60 seconds in milliseconds
</script>
```

This would initiate the conversion variables, and then schedule the `conversion.js` file to be injected 60 seconds later using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). After 60 seconds, it will dynamically inject `conversion.js`, which should detect your conversion variables and successfully track your conversion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.  I though I might need to use jquery or something but can see now that this is fairly easy.

Comment: Ah I have just realised that doing this will trigger multiple conversions per visit/visitor.  so I think I am going to extend this to set a 24hr cookie and use some logic to block multiple conversions.

Comment: @bigtony are you willing to share your adjusted code sample?

Comment: @Alex Sorry it was a long time ago and I don't have the code any more.

Comment: It should be easy to find how to set a cookie in javascript, then just wrap your tracking code in a conditional if block to check if the Cookie exists...good luck...  (By the way, this approach worked well for me! )